# Unbrick Galaxy S5

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I tried to install a CWM recovery on my G900F with Odin Mobile (using [these instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2697523)). But when the phone restarts, it just shows this:

[image: Recovery is not seandroid inforcing]

It says Recovery is not seandroid inforcing, Set Warranty Bit: recovery. It reboots avfter a few seconds, but then the same text is showing again.

First of all, what does it mean?

Second, any idea of what I should do?

By removing the battery and pressing volume down, home and power when returning the battery, I can get it to start in some Download mode, but I don't know if there's anything I can do. It says:

ODIN MODE PRODUCT NAME: SM-G900F

CURRENT BINARY: Samsung Official

SYSTEM STATUS: Custom

REACTIVATION LOCK(KK): OFF

KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 0x1 (2)

QUALCOMM SECUREBOOT: ENABLE (CSB)

RP SWREW: S1, T1, R1, A1,

P1 UOC START

Some forum posts suggest try flashing again, but when I connect the device to my laptop (Mac), it won't show up when i list devices in adb or fastboot.

Is there anything I can do?

(I've done this a few times before, but I still consider myself a beginner ...)

Comment: Hey, if I get an explanation for the downvote, I promise to write a better question the next time!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it at last. What I didn't know, was that with Odin, i can flash a custom recovery to the device, even though it didn't seem to respond to anything. Next time, I'll try Odin directly.

Here's a [good guide](http://androiding.how/how-to-install-twrp-recovery-using-odin/), if someone else is interested!